# SQLBindParameter with SQL_VARBINARY(MAX) gives "Invalid precision value"

Tags: sql-server

Using a C++ code, I am trying to insert a large binary blob into a MS SQL server using a stored procedure.  The table into which I am inserting is has 5 columns, types:

```
int
varchar
datetime
varbinary(max)
datetime
```

The stored procedure takes 4 parameters:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[spr_fff] 
     @act           AS INT
    ,@id            AS VARCHAR(255)
    ,@timestamp     AS DATETIME
    ,@blob          AS VARBINARY(MAX)
```

I set up my statement (with checks on return values that I am not showing):

```
const std::string queryString("{Call [spr_fff](?,?,?,?)}");
SQLHSTMT handle = NULL;
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, m_hConn, &handle);
SQLPrepare(handle, (SQLCHAR *)queryString.c_str(), SQL_NTS);
```

I bind the first three parameters with no problem, but I seem unable to figure out how to bind the 4th parameter. The code is essentially:

```
std::string sData; getData(sData);  //fills sData with the binary data
SQLLEN len1 = ???;
SQLBindParameter( handle, (SQLUSMALLINT)4, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_VARBINARY, len1, 0, (SQLCHAR*)&sData.c_str(), (SQLLEN)sData.size(), NULL);
```

and the trick seems to be figuring out what len1 should be.  If `sData.size() < 8000`, then `len1 = sData.size()` works fine.  But if `sData.size() > 8000`, nothing seems to work. If I set `len1 = sData.size()`, or `len1 = 2147483647` the call to `SQLBindParameter` results in the error code "Invalid precision value".  If I set `len1 = 0` as some of the (horrible) documentation seems to suggest, the call to `SQLBindParameter` works (for the 2008 native driver), but executing the statement results in a blob of size two, i.e. the two default 0 bytes with all the input blob data truncated to 0 bytes.  I have tried all these combinations with with all the client drivers listed below, all to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?????

Environment
   Client OS: Windows XP sp3

SQL Server is
         Microsoft SQL Server 09.00.3042

SQL Clients tried:
        Microsoft SQL Server Native Client Version 10.00.5500 (sqlncli10.dll, 2007.100.5500.00)
        Microsoft SQL Native Client Version 09.00.5000 (sqlncli.dll, 2005.90.5000.00)
        Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver Version 03.85.1132 (sqlsrv32.dll 2000.85.1132.0)

Comment: why are you filling a string variable with binary data? In .net it would use a SqlDbType.VarBinary as the parameter type. Maybe you need a byte array?

Comment: It makes no difference where I put the data.  I pass `SQLBindParameter` a pointer to the first byte of my data, and it doesn't know nor care how my code (the "outside world" as it were) has treated or characterized the data.  (Don't forget, this is what the cast `(SQLCHAR*)&sData.c_str()` does, essentially.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, the answer to my question is actually that I screwed up in the call to `SQLBindParameter`.  If you look at my code above, I have the final parameter as NULL.  A careful reading of the documentation - and believe me, it needs much careful reading! - shows that if the final parameter is NULL, the data is treated as zero-terminated.  ([the documentation for `SQLBindParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms710963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#sectionToggle12) says "If StrLen_or_IndPtr is a null pointer, the driver assumes that all input parameter values are non-NULL **and that character and binary data is null-terminated**." - emphasis mine)  And, by unfortunate coincidence, the data I was supplying had a zero as the second or third byte, so the blob that was actually stored was only 1 or 2 bytes.  Not sure why it worked with a size under 8000 - there may have been some interplay with size<8000 and various driver versions, but I haven't taken the time to tease that out.

Also, in the code above I state "If I set `len1 = 0` as some of the (horrible) documentation seems to suggest,".  This is in fact the correct thing to do.

The correct code is thus

```
SQLLEN len1 = 0;
SQLLEN nThisLen = (SQLLEN)sData.size();
SQLBindParameter( handle, (SQLUSMALLINT)4, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_BINARY, SQL_VARBINARY, len1, 0, (SQLCHAR*)&sData.c_str(), nThisLen, &nThisLen );
```

Answer (score 0):

Jeff O was on the right track. Try changing your sproc to...

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[spr_fff] 
    @act           AS INT
    ,@id           AS VARCHAR(255)
    ,@timestamp    AS DATETIME
    ,@preblob      AS nvarchar(MAX)

    DECLARE @blob varbinary(MAX) = CAST(@preblob as varbinary(MAX))
    /* Continue using varbinary blob as before */
```

Note the change of your sproc's parameter datatype and the subsequent cast to varbinary.

Cheers.